# Embed PDF File to HTML Web Page for Which data is coming from Backend Server

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

Trying to Embed PDF into my HTML Web Page for which I am calling an AJAX function.

The function retrieves the data from my backend of the PDF but instead of rendering that as PDF, my frame keep showing the data of that PDF as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Any suggestion on how to make my page render it into PDF, as webpages by default support showing PDFs.

My data from backend is in `byte[]` format, further suggestion to improve

Answer (score 0):

So I had asked this question. And, after some research, I found out that the approach was right, but I was omitting crucial headers which indicated that the data being sent from the backend is to be rendered as PDF or image.

So if any one working on spring boot and facing same problem can follow this:

1. Controller – endpoints mapping:

   [image: 1]

   ```java
   @GetMapping(
       path = "/documentExplore/{documentId}",
       produces ={
           MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,
           MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE
       }
   )
   public byte[] viewDocument (@PathVariable(value = "documentId") Long documentId)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException, DocumentException
   {            
       return scannerService.getDocumentData(documentId);
   }
   ```
2. ScannerService Interface

   ```java
   byte[] getDocumentData (Long documentId) throws IOException, DocumentException;
   ```
3. ScannerService Implementation – this renders PDF as well convert image into PDF for viewing

   ```java
   @Override
   public byte[] getDocumentData(Long documentId) throws IOException, DocumentException
   {
       Document document = documentRepository.findById(documentId).get();
       Path documentPath = Paths.get(uploadPath + document.getDocumentPath());

       if(document.getDocumentExtension().contains("png")) {
           Image image = Image.getInstance(Files.readAllBytes(documentPath));
           float height = image.getHeight();
           float width = image.getWidth();
           String tmpdir = Files
                           .createTempDirectory("DmsCache")
                           .toFile()
                           .getAbsolutePath();
           System.out.println(tmpdir);
           com.itextpdf.text.Document doc = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

           Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(width,height);
           doc.setPageSize(pageSize);
           PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(tmpdir+"/doc.pdf"));

           doc.open();
           doc.add(image);
           doc.close();

           Path tempPath = Paths.get(tmpdir+"/doc.pdf");
           byte[] documentData = Files.readAllBytes(tempPath);
           System.out.println("Img");
           return documentData;
       }
       else {
           byte[] documentData = Files.readAllBytes(documentPath);
           System.out.println("Pdf");
           return documentData;
       }

   }
   ```
4. My JavaScript call method to dynamically render different files and embed into frame

   ```js
   function readDocument(x){
       console.log(x.parentElement);
       console.log(x.parentElement.children);
       var documentId = x.parentElement.children.item(1).textContent;

       var urlDoc = 'http://localhost:8080/data/documentExplore/' + documentId;
       var viewElement = document.getElementById("dockit");
       viewElement.children.item(0).remove();

       var newObjectEl = document.createElement("embed");
       newObjectEl.type="application/pdf"
       newObjectEl.src=urlDoc.valueOf();
       newObjectEl.width="100%"
       newObjectEl.height="100%"

       viewElement.append(newObjectEl);
   }
   ```
5. HTML embed tag to embed the rendered PDF into webpage:

   ```html
   <div class="window-main-body" id="dockit">
       <embed
           type="application/pdf"
           src=""
           width="100%"
           height="100%"
       >
   </div>
   ```
6. Due to security reason, embedding is generally disabled for which we have to manually configure these setting into spring boot:

   ```java
   .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
   ```

   The above should be added to Security Filter Chain in security configuration.

Answer (score -1):

`<a href="file.pdf">PDF</a>`, simply set up an anchor tag like this, you can also add up a button in between or keep the plain text. Now, when your PDF text is clicked, your pdf document shall open in pdf format

mail me at mulla786mohammedumar@yahoo.com for further queries :)

Comment: So sir, there is little misunderstanding on the question so i want my html page to render it has pdf only to show by its default pdf viewer

Comment: <a href="file.pdf">PDF</a>, simply set up an anchor tag like this, you can also add up a button in between or keep the plain text. Now, when your PDF text is clicked, your pdf document shall open in pdf format

Comment: Why did you do so much coding only simple anchor tag was also ok, even that can be effective

Comment: There is so much coding because data fetching is from my backend and its dynamically picking those files from my DMS library and the anchor tag will make that file download while my aim is to embed it into the page for view there on the page it self, similar to those web apps where you can select file and preview them beside them, also this code includes conversion of image and other docs such as .docx, .xlsx into pdf for viewing and this is spring boot application so i had pasted my code for future reference if any one utilises the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can then set target attribute as _self of anchor tag, then anchor tag opens in the same page and if you want to open it into a particular section of the page then you can also use fields for that purpose as fields divides the page